# Import error - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model'

Tags: python, tensorflow, module, importerror

I am trying to replicate the example mentioned at this address by tensorlayer:

https://github.com/tensorlayer/srgan/blob/master/train.py

It has below import statements:

```
import time, random
import numpy as np
import scipy, multiprocessing
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorlayer as tl
from model import get_G, get_D
from config import config
```

But this statement is throwing error: `from model import get_G, get_D`

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model'
```

I am unable to find such package on 'pypi.org'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `model` you imported is a custom module, it is placed in this repo `srgan`, you got to clone the dependency of `train.py` too.